# How do "nested" #includes work in C?

Tags: c, header

Lets say there is a library/API or a bunch of code I want to use (written by someone else) and it's stored in an arbitrary folder (like C:\randoAPIs\coolStuff\includes). Let say my main.c is in a different folder like C:\MyCProjects\coolProject and to use the coolStuff API, I add this include path to my IDE and add #include "coolStuff.h"; and it works fine.

Here's the question:

Lets say that "coolStuff.h" itself includes some other header file like #include "boringStuff.h"; **Where does the compiler *look* for boringStuff.h?** Is is in my main.c folder? or in coolStuff's includes folder? Any/all folders in my include path? **Or is this a compiler specific issue and I should just go read that documentation**

Comment: All of these are compiler-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely implementation-defined. [C11 6.10.2p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.2p3):

> 3 A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include "q-char-sequence" new-line
> ```
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters. **The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner.** If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>
> ```
> # include <h-char-sequence> new-line
> ```
>
> with the identical contained sequence (including `>` characters, if any) from the original directive.

Notice that the `#include "coolStuff.h"` need not be supported. Additionally `#include "coolStuff.h"` can even map to something like `#include <COOLSTUF.H>`. [C11 6.10.2p5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.2p5):

> 5 The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (6.4.2.1) followed by a period (.) and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a digit. The implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical case and restrict the mapping to eight significant characters before the period.

Comment: Have you seen a C compiler which does not support #include "xxxx"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a 'standard' or 'conventional' way compilers handle this? Or are implementations generally completely different?

Comment: @MCHatora - This *is* the standard way to handle this. Note that there are C compilers for operating systems that doesn't even *have* directories. Or paths.

Answer (score 0):

It is the compiler dependant but I would suggest to add your own include directory in your project and keep your include files there. Then just add this path(s) to the include search list in your compiler. For example for gcc (windows) `-I"path"`